# Variable value in the event

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a combobox that have a change handler - switch()

```
function switch() {
    var type= $('#ddType').val();
    search.keydown(function (event) {
         if (type == "SomeCode" &&....
}
```

This code fires every time when i change a combobox value (k.o)
But in the keydown handler *type* variable has always a first default value of the combobox so i must do something like that

```
search.keydown(function (event) {
    type = $('#ddType').val();
    if (type == "SomeCode" &&....
}
```

Why that? If again the *type* in the first line of method work's fine and changing a type value to the current selected value and a keypress event initialize each time when we change combobox selection? Why keypress *type* value has an old first value?
Thx

Comment: Are you sure that code *fires*? `switch` is a reserved word, you should be getting an error for naming your function so.

Comment: I just simplify titles and as i said debugger allows me to go through the each line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of this behavior is that keypress event every time adds a new handler, but it's fires up only first one. So the first one operates with old values.
Solution - to unbind handlers before add a new one.

```
function switch() {
    search.unbind('keydown');
    search.keydown(function (event) {
         if (type == "SomeCode" &&....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

bfavaretto is right. Switch is reserved and can't be used as a function name.

Answer (score 0):

try to use `keyup` instead of `keydown`

Comment: there is no matter what event to use: keydown, keyup, keypress, blur